# why restoring database never finishes?

Tags: sql-server, database-restore

I have really wired problems here. I am using MS 2008 sql server at the moment. After I did a tail-log backup, the target database is automatically restoring and keeping on restoring.

Does anyone know what's the problem?

Thanks,
Ling

Comment: Please get in the habit of **accepting** the best answer provided, the one solving your problem. It's the right and polite thing to do on StackOverflow and serves as an incentive for others to continue to help those looking for answers. See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/accepting-answers-what-is-it-all-about

Answer (score 1):

It's most likely because you didn't restore with the WITH RECOVERY option.

Comment: Thanks Dave, the question is I could not remember I did restore or not. I am only sure that I did the tail_log backup in the last operation. it is really wired.